Using Look up tables with Raydium swap
I'm currently trying to write a multiple swap transaction (10 swaps) using lookup tables using Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple.
When writing standard v0 transactions, you simply pass the LUT to compileToV0Message([LUT]) and it works, though i'm struggling to work out how to add the LUT to a Raydium sdk built tx.
Is this possible? Or do i have to write the swap from scratch?

If you already have a compiled transaction from the Raydium SDK, it's a bit tricky to add an address lookup table. You'll need to deconstruct the message and then replace the addresses with ones from lookup table accounts.

import {
    LOOKUP_TABLE_CACHE,
} from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk'

You can use lookup table like this.
But in my experience, I can perform raydium swap without lookup table.
I think lookup table is required when you use several instructions in one tx.
